# android master detail pattern with navigation library and fragments

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I want to create a simple 2 pane layout with fragments and navigation component on tablet.
Is it possible with jetpack ? I cant find any example how to set up navigation component.

On top of that on tablet 2 pane fragment layout is ok, but on phone I would like to show master fragment in full screen and detail fragment in smaller popup which will be still fragment. It should be in FrameLayout, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

    </data>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="false" />


        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_graph" />

    </FrameLayout>

</layout>
```

Comment: It's possible if you don't use `NavHostFragment` and implement `FragmentNavigator` yourself in such a way that it would support master-detail.

Comment: Great question. I was looking for something similar and stumbled into an article that may help future visitors - https://proandroiddev.com/master-detail-views-with-navigation-components-a20405f31974